# How do you change button color when it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

Im doing a school project where I'm coding a website for extra credit, so I'm trying to make it look as fancy as possible.

My main goal right now is to let a button change color when its clicked, like how it shows which page is selected on the multi-page website. Please someone help quick, it's due in a week and I got a LOT of fancying to do.

Oh yeah, it's on a learners website (-_-) so right now I'm limited to types of code I can use.

Thanks please help me quickly.

Comment: So what is your issue again ?

Comment: Did you even try something?

Comment: I suggest going through this before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will make it easier for yourself and for us.

Comment: Please do not add information that is irrelevant for the question, such as when your project is due or the time in which you are expecting a reply.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "learners website"? It would be helpful if you stated how you are going about making your website (the tools and technologies you are using, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my simple way of doing it for beginners and that's how I started out and learning. Also my CodePen is here if you want to try it and see it working: [CodePen for Changing Colors onclick](https://codepen.io/sonofb/pen/moWpqB)

```js
function changeColor(){
document.getElementsByClassName("myButton")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<button class="myButton" style="background-color:blue;" onclick="changeColor()">Change Color</button>
```